# Riez representation theorem does not hold on infinite-dimensional vector spaces example

Tags: linear-algebra, riesz-representation-theorem

Show that the Riesz Representation Theorem does not hold on infinite-dimensional vector spaces without any hypotheses on the vector space V and linear functional.

Comment: What hypotheses?

Comment: I meant without any hypotheses on the vector space and linear functional.

Answer (score 2):

Put on the vector space $V$ of all real sequences $(x_n)_{n\geq1}$ whose entries are almost all zero the evident inner space, and consider the map $V\to\mathbb R$ which maps such a sequence to the sum of its entries.